# Coffeescript, the Facebook JS API and scope

Tags: javascript, facebook, coffeescript

I am using Coffeescript and am loading the Facebook JS api asynchronously, as they suggest in their documentation. Like so:

```
#Load the FB api asynchronously
(->
  e = document.createElement("script")
  e.async = true
  e.src = document.location.protocol + "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
  document.getElementById("fb-root").appendChild e
)()

doSomething = () ->
  # I'd like to call this from the FB context 

window.fbAsyncInit = ->
  FB.init 
    appId: fb_app_id
    status: true
    cookie: true
    xfbml: true
    oauth: true

  # Doesn't work. Is out of scope. 
  doSomething()
```

With the Facebook stuff attached to `window`, I can't access the stuff in the Coffeescript's anonymous wrapper function context.

I know I could define my function as `window.doSomething()`, but am not sure if this is the best way.

Is there a way to have the Facebook stuff load within the context of the Coffeescript's anonymous wrapper function?

Comment: What's the exact error that you're experiencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in thinking that you shouldn't pollute the global namespace. One way to continue having a clean environment (get it :) is to use a class and keep your Facebook specific functions in there.

This might help get you started:

```
class MyFacebookApp 
  constructor: ->
  doSomething: () ->
    console.log "I'm doing something over here."

window.myFacebookApp = new MyFacebookApp()
window.fbAsyncInit = ->
  FB.init 
    appId: fb_app_id
    status: true
    cookie: true
    xfbml: true
    oauth: true

  myFacebookApp.doSomething()
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

That's not a scope issue. If you look at the compiled JS, you'll see `var doSomething` declared at the top of the file. Moreover, `doSomething` is set to its proper value before `window.FBAsyncInit`.